# Autodesk Viewer on Online Server

Tags: performance, https, web-deployment, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have implemented the Autodesk Viewer API and it is working great as long as we are in my local environment.

But the application in which the viewer has been integrated has been deployed on online server and since then there are several bugs in the viewer. It takes longer to load the file or sometimes doesn’t load it at all.

Are there more configurations required while deploying on an online server? Especially when it is a secure one (https)?

Do we need to convert our free trial to a subscription to have higher performance ?

There still is 86 cloud credits left in the free trial but we are ready to switch to a subscription if necessary.

Your help will be highly appreciated. I'm looking forward to your answers.

Kind regards,

A.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no performance differences and no limitations between running your Forge-based server code locally vs publicly, or via HTTP vs HTTPS. Please send us more details about the stack you're using in an email to forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com and we'll take a look at it.